# using php to insert records in my database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert data into my database from a user form using php
I normally do not have any issues when doing this except this time and I believe it is because of the date type as explained below

Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();    
$user = $_SESSION['who'];

if (!$_SESSION['who']){
    header("location: login.php");
}    

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    require_once('dbconn.php');
    $flightID = $_POST["flights"];       

    $sql= "INSERT INTO booking (flight_id,customer_id,checkedin,checkin_datetime, booking_datetime,baggage)
            VALUES ('1', '1','0','10-10-10', '10-10-10','30')";

    if($recordSet = $dbConn->query($sql)) {
        echo "record set";
    }
    else
        echo "not set";
}    
?>
```

I will be using variables instead of hard coded values for my insert statement however I am just trying to get it to work.

Here are the attributes in my database table for booking

id, flight_id,  customer_id, checkedin, checkin_datetime, booking_datetime, baggage

The ID is automatic which is why it is not in my sql statement

currently my page is displaying `not set` I think it may be due to the date field as I am not sure which format it may use.

UPDATE: I changed the date in my sql statement and it still is not working, no errors coming up as well.

Comment: You use Date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: Try to print error which is generated while you are executing your query i.e: check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) .

Comment: @Swati thank you so much i never knew about that, turns out my ID field was not auto-increment so i needed it in my database

Answer (score 3):

You can Use

```
$sql= "INSERT into booking (flight_id,customer_id,checkedin,checkin_datetime, booking_datetime,baggage)
            VALUES ('1', '1','0','2020-10-10', '2020-10-10','30')";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO booking (flight_id,customer_id,checkedin,checkin_datetime, booking_datetime,baggage)
        VALUES ('1', '1','0','2010-10-20', '2010-10-20','30')";
```

**Note :**

- date format: YYYY-MM-DD
- All id must be exists in the database (if you use Foreign Key for `flight_id` and `customer_id`).

Answer (score 0):

Date format looks ok in the sql statement.

make sure **ID** field is auto increment in the database as you have not used in the sql statement.